# Terminals like Terminator or Guake terminal are not able to parse prompt profiles for git which is set in .bashrc file

Tags: terminal, git, bashrc, guake

Terminals like Terminator or Guake terminal are not able to parse prompt profiles for git which is set in .bashrc file. PS1 variable is not set for terminals which use xterm as base which guake and terminator terminals use.
So if custom functions are used for instance for displaying custom path if current directory is GIT directory then those variables or functions will not work.

Eg:  $parse_git_branch

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Before setting PS1][image: After setting PS1]

I figured out the solution, it was with .bashrc file in my home directory.
If we Open this file in text editor, here we will find a line where it's checking if the current terminal is xterm or not and setting some value to it:

`# If this is an xterm set the title to user@host:dir
case "$TERM" in
xterm*|rxvt*)
    PS1="\[\e]0;${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\u@\h: \w\a\]$PS1"
    ;;
*)
    ;;
esac`

So just comment given PS1 using # and then simply replace PS1 with this value:

```
    parse_git_branch() {
  git branch 2> /dev/null | sed -e '/^[^*]/d' -e 's/* \(.*\)/(\1)/'
}

# If this is an xterm set the title to user@host:dir
# old value:PS1="\[\e]0;${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\u@\h: \w\a\]$PS1"

case "$TERM" in
xterm*|rxvt*)
    PS1="${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\[\033[1;34m\]\H:\[\033[1;35m\]\[\033[1;35m\]\w\[\033[1;92m\]\$(parse_git_branch)\[\033[0m\]$ "
    ;;
*)
    ;;
esac
```